# How can I add a JSON object created with angularjs to an array on my server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, server

I'm mainly a front-end devloper, so the basic server-side aspect of the project I'm working on is escaping me.

My main webpage has a list of products pulled from a JSON array with angularjs' ng-repeat, but I'd like to add an administrative page in which authenticated users could push a JSON object to the array. How can I do this with no experience in any server-side scripting languages?

Comment: What are you using server-side?  And how are you retrieving the original JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bringer of bad news, but when dealing with user permissions, you need to be using some kind of back-end technology.

Theoretically, you could store authentication information in the JSON that denoted whether or not a user is an admin, and display the content/assign permissions accordingly. The problem with this technique is that, since the code is on the client side, hacking the admin page would be as easy as altering the JavaScript. This method would provide literally no security whatsoever.

If this is okay with you, then go ahead. But I would strongly advise learning some kind of server-side technology.

Given that you're a font-end developer, I'm assuming you already know JavaScript, so maybe doing this in [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) would be a good option. Node does have a learning curve in and of itself, but knowing JavaScript will help significantly. You'll also need some kind of basic database to store the login information. Some kind of noSQL dialect such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) would probably work well here.

For doing advanced permissions, you'd want to use something like LDAP or Active Directory, but for what you're describing this would probably be overkill.

Remember, learning new things is fun! Good luck!